# problems with Dialogflow and Microsoft bot emulator

Tags: botframework, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

My internship wants me to build a bot in dialog flow and test it in Microsoft bot emulator but I don't know how to convert what I have build into a AIP or a URL link and that is needed to import the bot into Microsoft bot emulator

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the Bot community custom adapter

1. https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.Google
2. https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.ActionsSDK